How to automatically add a multiplier in Excel when using date functions
I am trying to make a Gantt chart wherein a row will be filled with date ranges. For each cell in the row it will consist of two dates, the start day of the week and the end day of the week. I can start with a starting to to reference.
A1: =DATE(2024, 3, 31)
A2: =TEXT($A$1+7*0,"mm/dd")&" - "&TEXT($A$1+6*1,"mm/dd")
A3: =TEXT($A$1+7*1,"mm/dd")&" - "&TEXT($A$1+6*2,"mm/dd")

I am assuming that Excel can automatically fill A4 and beyond with this:
A4: =TEXT($A$1+7*2,"mm/dd")&" - "&TEXT($A$1+6*3,"mm/dd")
A5: =TEXT($A$1+7*3,"mm/dd")&" - "&TEXT($A$1+6*4,"mm/dd")
A6: =TEXT($A$1+7*4,"mm/dd")&" - "&TEXT($A$1+6*5,"mm/dd")

In my mind, the multipliers should progress as I extend the row such that it will fill succeeding date ranges. But the case is not. How should I create the the excel algorithm such that the multipliers will progress based on the pattern?

Maybe you could define a row called row or factor witch you increase by one and use this as factor.

or multiply by the row number - subtract a constant to start with 1.

I don't have much experience with it, but when you want to play with first day of week, you might learn how to use the WORKDAY.INTL() function.

7 * ROWS($1:2) and fill down.

If you want the multiplier to scale as you go down I would use a row function, pulling back the value by 2 since the first instance of 0 is on row 2. Re-writing your formulas it would look like this
A1: =DATE(2024, 3, 31)
A2: =TEXT($A$1+7*(ROW()-2),"mm/dd")&" - "&TEXT($A$1+6* (ROW()-1),"mm/dd")
A3: =TEXT($A$1+7*(ROW()-2),"mm/dd")&" - "&TEXT($A$1+6*(ROW()-1),"mm/dd")
To explain how this works, in cell A2, ROW() says "2" as the result, so the first instance I subtracted 2 to make it 0, and the second case in the same formula by 1 to make it 1.
